# Passing variables to React components gives "unknown property errror"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Super simple or so I thought! Just trying to pass a string to another component but it doesn't recognize the property because it is using string interpolation.

**edit**

I believe it could be related to upgrading redux-form which changed the input selector. I'm using React 15.3.1 and I believe they changed how inputs worked which affected Redux. (https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1249).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

import errorListItem from '../error-list-item/index.js';

class Signup extends Component {
  handleFormSubmit(formProps) {
    this.props.signupUser(formProps);
  }

  renderAlert() {
    const errorObject = this.props.errorMessage;

    // single (connection/api) error
    if (errorObject === 'Network Error') {
      return (
        <div className="alert alert-danger">
          <errorListItem message="hello" />
        </div>
      );

    // error object from BE
    } else if (errorObject && typeof errorObject === 'object') {
      const keys = Object.keys(errorObject);

      debugger;
      if (keys.length === 0) return;

      return Object.keys(errorObject).map(field => {
        return errorObject[field].map(problem => {
          const message = `${field} ${field}`;

          return (
           <ul className="error-message-list">
              <errorListItem message={message} />
            </ul>
           );
        });
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, fields: { email, password, passwordConfirm, username }} = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="signup">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
          <fieldset className="form-group">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input className="form-control" {...username} />
            {username.touched && username.error && <div className="error">{username.error}</div>}
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset className="form-group">
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input className="form-control" {...email} />
            {email.touched && email.error && <div className="error">{email.error}</div>}
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset className="form-group">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" className="form-control" {...password} />
            {password.touched && password.error && <div className="error">{password.error}</div>}
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset className="form-group">
            <label>Confirm Password:</label>
            <input className="form-control" {...passwordConfirm} />
            {passwordConfirm.touched && passwordConfirm.error && <div className="error">{passwordConfirm.error}</div>}
          </fieldset>
          <button action="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
        </form>
        {this.renderAlert()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function validate(formProps) {
  const errors = {};

  if (!formProps.email) {
    errors.email = 'Please enter an email';
  }

  if (!formProps.password) {
    errors.password = 'Please enter a password';
  }

  if (!formProps.passwordConfirm) {
    errors.passwordConfirm = 'Please enter a password confirmation';
  }

  if (!formProps.username) {
    errors.username = 'Please enter a username';
  }

  // Passwords match
  if (formProps.password !== formProps.passwordConfirm) {
    errors.password = 'Passwords must match';
  }

  return errors;
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { errorMessage: state.auth.errors };
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'signup',
  fields: ['email', 'password', 'passwordConfirm', 'username'],
  validate
}, mapStateToProps, actions)(Signup);
```

Child component:

```
import React from 'react';

require('./styles.scss');

const errorListItem = ({ message }) => {
  return (<li>{message}</li>)
}

export default errorListItem;
```

Attempted Solutions:

1. Passing the property without using a variable

   ```
   <ul className="error-message-list">
     <errorListItem message={`${field}  ${problem}`} />
   </ul>
   ```
2. Passing the property using ES6 destructuring

   ```
   <ul className="error-message-list">
     <errorListItem message />
   </ul>
   ```
3. Passing the property using older JS syntax without ``.

   ```
     const message = "" + field + " " +  problem + "";

     return (
       <ul className="error-message-list">
         <errorListItem message={message} />
       </ul>
      );
   ```
4. Try to make the child component render anything!

   ```
     const errorListItem = ({ message }) => {
       return <li>Help Me, Obi-Wan Kenobi. You're My Only Hope</li>
     }
   ```

Documentation consulted:

https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html

Error Message:

```
Warning: Unknown prop `message` on <errorListItem> tag. Remove this prop from the element.
```

Expected Behavior:

1. It should be able to pass a string as a property. If I use the below, it will work:

   ```
   <ul className="error-message-list">
     <errorListItem message='message' />
   </ul>
   ```
2. If it doesn't render, the error message should not be "unknown property" but instead invalid property value given.

Versions:

```
"react": "^0.14.3",
"react-redux": "^4.0.0",
"react-router": "^2.0.1",
"redux": "^3.0.4",
"redux-form": "^5.3.1",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is in how you've named your `errorListItem` component. In JSX, custom component names should start with an uppercase letter, while normal html ones in lowercase. So React thinks you're trying to render a "normal" tag called `errorListItem` with an unknown property. The error shows up because React validates the props passed to html tags: https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html

Try to rename your stateless component when you import it (and to be consistent also when you define it) in this way:

```
import ErrorListItem from '../error-list-item/index.js';
// Rest of your code...
<ErrorListItem message={message} />
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think it would fail because of that. Good catch and it works as expected.

Comment: Yeah... same here. Making the variable name being used upper case, solves it all.